# Found an error in data after conference paper submission deadline

Tags: paper-submission, errors-erratum

I submitted a paper to a top conference in my field. I found an error in my data several hours before the deadline. I tried to resubmit. However, the submission website required checking my paper through IEEE PDF eXpress before submission and the IEEE PDF eXpress website was down. Eventually, I was not able to resubmit the new version of my paper. The old version has a significant error, as in the text, my performance number is 673, but in the figure, it says 672. I don't know how to fix this. Will my paper get rejected because of this?

Comment: Writing 672 instead of 673 looks to me like just a typo, which is nowhere near a reason for rejection (if anyone even notices it).

Comment: What leads you to the conclusion that this is a "significant error"?

Comment: I have no idea what a "performance number" is, but in some contexts it might matter that 672=2x2x2x2x2x3x7 whereas 673 is prime, or there might be a regulation saying that some particular thing must not exceed 672, or maybe everybody knows Emperor Rambalf III was assassinated in the year 672 and therefore could not be the author of a decree that the paper says was promulgated in the year 673.